# Is polygamy allowed for Hindus in the state of Goa, India, if there is "no children or no male child"?

Tags: law, india

Usman Qazi wrote in a Quora post:

> I was just reading about Hindu Family Law in the state of Goa, India,
>   under which polygamy is allowed in case of there being no children or
>   no male child. I don’t know if permission from the previous wife (or
>   wives) is required.
>
> [Source](https://www.quora.com/How-does-a-Muslim-wife-feel-when-her-husband-comes-home-with-a-new-wife/answer/Usman-Qazi?srid=xyhZ)

Is it true?

Comment: I've removed the off topic subquestions, please stay on topic.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, according to multiple sources.

[The Politics of Personal Law](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=YwvaaHI8sjEC&lpg=PA19&pg=PA19#v=onepage&q&f=false), By Partha S. Ghosh, page 19

> ... Hindu men have the right to polygamy, but only under specific circumstances keeping in view the Codes of Usages and Customs of Gentile Hindus of Goa, of Daman and of Diu. This is also more in theory than practice (Desay 1996)

[image: book extract]

[Mahajan, G.; Surinder S. Jodhka. Religion, Community and Development: Changing Contours of Politics and Policy in India. (2010) 312 pp. ISBN 978-0-415-58566-8](http://www.routledge.com/books/details/9780415585668/), page 310

[image: another book extract]